# What is a good standard size for uploaded photos?

Tags: image-resizing

I'm building a little image hosting site and I'm wondering if there are any best practices regarding image resizing?

Longest side 1024px? 960px?

Thanks!

Comment: New MBP is 2880x1800, so I suggest always storing the original image then using [a single-source imaging library like the one I offer](http://imageresizing.net) to generate cached variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/web-screen-resolution-usage-statistics.php

> However, over the years with increased use of high resolution monitors
>   the number of people using 800x600 screen resolutions has gradually
>   fallen

I would use that information to decide which display will be usable to most users, and then also take into account things like the file size of such images on the server, etc.  Or, you could go another route and just ask the user their preference on resizing, it's up to you.

It also has a nice graph:

[image]